# Accessing local variables in asm

Tags: java, local-variables, java-bytecode-asm

I am trying to get info about the local variables in a method using the code below:

```
public void foo(ClassNode cn){
        for(MethodNode mn : cn.methods){
            System.out.println("# of local variables: " + mn.localVariables.size());
            if(mn.parameters != null)
                System.out.println("# of parameters: " + mn.parameters.size());
            else
                System.out.println("# of parameters: 0");
            System.out.println("Class name: " + cn.name);
            System.out.println("Method name: " + mn.name);
            System.out.println("Method signature: " + mn.desc);

            for(final LocalVariableNode local : (List<LocalVariableNode>)mn.localVariables) {
                System.out.println("Local Variable: " + local.name + " : " + local.desc + " : " + local.signature + " : " + local.index);
            }
        }

    }
```

The problem is that I keep getting an empty list for mn.localVariables and the parameters list is always null. I looked at a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807016/accessing-local-variables-in-the-asm-java-library) since it is what I am trying to acheive but it did not resolve the issue. Any idea on how I can solve this?

Some functions I am testing the code on:

```
 public static void testLocals(boolean one) {
        String two = "hello local variables";
        one = true;
        int three = 64;
    }

public int switchMethod2(int i) {
    int j = 0;
    switch (i) {
    case 0: j = 0; break;
    case 1000: j = 1; break;
    case 2000: j = 2; break;
    default: j = -1;
    }
    return j;
}

public int switchMethod3(int i) {
    int j = 0;
    switch (i) {
    default: j = -1;
    }
    return j;
}
```

Comment: Local variables are only available when the associated debug attribute is present. Likewise, parameters are only available if the code has been compiled with Java 8 or newer, with the `-parameters` option.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you compile java with -g option like below?
javac -g XXX.java

-g option generate all debugging informa